# Serverless offline path issue Error: Invalid path: ///stag/upadmin/user

Tags: node.js, express, serverless-framework, hapi.js, aws-serverless

I am getting following error when running serverless offline.

**My current configuration :**

Node: 16.19.1
"serverless": "^2.72.3",
"serverless-offline": "^8.2.0",\

But application worked when I was using **"serverless-offline": "^5.12.1"**

```
Error: Invalid path: ///stag/upadmin/user
      at new module.exports (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\@hapi\hoek\lib\error.js:23:19)
      at Object.module.exports [as assert] (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\@hapi\hoek\lib\assert.js:21:11)
      at exports.Router.internals.Router.internals.Router.analyze (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\@hapi\call\lib\index.js:208:10)
      at new module.exports.internals.Route (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\route.js:99:44)
      at internals.Server._addRoute (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\server.js:524:23)
      at internals.Server.route (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\server.js:517:22)
      at HttpServer.createRoutes (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\events\http\HttpServer.js:898:57)
      at Http._create (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\events\http\Http.js:43:65)
      at D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\events\http\Http.js:52:12
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Http.create (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\events\http\Http.js:47:12)
      at ServerlessOffline._createHttp (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\ServerlessOffline.js:230:53)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at async ServerlessOffline.start (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\ServerlessOffline.js:145:5)
      at async PluginManager.runHooks (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:601:35)
      at async PluginManager.invoke (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:639:9)
      at async PluginManager.run (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:700:7)
      at async Serverless.run (D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:468:5)
      at async D:\UpNorway\workspace\forks\booking-app\insider-app\node_modules\serverless\scripts\serverless.js:836:9
```

I was tried using **serverless-plugin-typescript** as well still didn't work